# Implementing Universal search in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, global

I have a rails 4 application with number of models and view pages. The application layout of my application contains a search bar. But it is inactive as of now. The purpose of search bar is to allow user to search through all the models for the keyword(s) entered, basically making it a global search. Is there any gem which does universal search? Or it has to be done manually through sql queries?
I could see way to implement search for a specific model on its view page. But I want it to search through all the models at once. How should I go about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best way in your case is to use ElasticSearch. A neat integration gem is provided [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails). Links to documentation are provided on that page.

Comment: Doesn't the gem create an index per model ? is there a way to create one index for all the models ?, or alternatively how do you search once on multiple indices ? pointing me to a link is good enough for me.

Comment: How about pg_search gem? Is it worth enough. Because My database is not too huge to afford sunspot.

Comment: @VivekTripathi well, if your search is that simple, you could ofcource use `pg_search`, but that means that you get stuck to your DB and it's not quite scalable when your app grows.

Comment: @Almaron, Now that's a practical and very valid point. Thanks for the suggestion. Do we have any demo or sample code that guides me from model to controller to view? I mean fully functional search form already implemented, so that it reduces extra effort.

Comment: @VivekTripathi a brief Google search for "Elasticsearch rails example" gives quite a number of interesting tutorials like this one: http://www.sitepoint.com/full-text-search-rails-elasticsearch.

Comment: The tutorial shows search facility for a single model. Is there some way we can generate global search results from across the models i have in my app.

Answer (score 5):

One of the good approach for it will be to use `gem 'searchkick'`
which uses elasticsearch.

**Resources for Searchkick:**
https://github.com/ankane/searchkick
https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#advanced

Answer (score 3):

[Sunspot](https://rubygems.org/gems/sunspot) is one of the most used gem to add search in a Rails app.

Indexing looks like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    text :title, :body
    text :comments do
      comments.map { |comment| comment.body }
    end
    integer :blog_id
    integer :author_id
    integer :category_ids, :multiple => true
    time :published_at
    string :sort_title do
      title.downcase.gsub(/^(an?|the)\b/, '')
    end
  end
end
```

And searching:

```
Post.search do
  fulltext 'best pizza'
  with :blog_id, 1
  with(:published_at).less_than Time.now
  order_by :published_at, :desc
  paginate :page => 2, :per_page => 15
  facet :category_ids, :author_id
end
```

Comment: Sunspot allows single search across multiple models